How to use sub queries in MS Access DB--So far not working
I tried
SELECT 2 - (SELECT 1);
and got
" Syntax error in query '2 - (SELECT 1)' "

Look up a tutorial on Beginning with SQL or similar.

@jarlh, not always. "SELECT 1" works fine.

I see. (I've never used Access.)

@Gustav, I am already quite familiar with SQL. I have been using joins and aliases and aggregate functions. It's just this particular problem I have and I can't seem to find anything useful with the usual Google Search.

Duplicate covers the same issue: Access disallows subqueries without a FROM, so either you need to create a dual table yourself, or use something like (SELECT FIRST(ID) FROM MSysObjects) As DUAL

we can't directly use sub queries in the select clause like it can be accessible in other databases like mysql or Postgresql. To achieve the same result we should add the FROM clause.
SELECT 2 - subquery.result
FROM (SELECT 1 AS result) AS subquery;


Will test soon.

This does not work. Access says: Query input must contain at least one table or query

RESOLVED (After reading duplicate):
SELECT
2 - one.result
FROM
(
SELECT
1 AS result
FROM
MSysResources
) AS one;
